# Plotting Geohash data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geohashing

Has anyone had any luck in importing data that has Geohash as a field into QGIS for any visualizations?

Ultimately my data is -

```
Name, Geohash, Value
Bob, 9mu9ecy, 3
Nancy, 9mu9ecy, 8
Nancy, 9mu9eff, 5
Tom, 9mu9ege, 5
Bob, 9mu9ege, 5
Mike, 9mu9emx, 8
Tom, 9mu9ep3, 7
Nancy, 9mu9epf, 2
Nancy, 9mu9epp, 4
...
```

And I want to be able to create heatmaps and differential analysis with it.

Any help would be much appreciated.